# Change center of rotation for a text using inline CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

I want to make sure my text attributes rotates around its own lower left corner.
It is defined as such :

```
<text x="26" y="46.99804139845162" transform="rotate(90)">blabla</text>
```

I have tried to do

```
 <text x="26" y="49" style="transform-origin: 0% 0%"
transform="rotate(90)">blabla</text>
```

but to no avail as it seems to rotate around the same point.

Any help is welcome.

Comment: if you are working with css, try "rotate(90deg)". And maybe the two times "transform" is causing some issues!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zhSRq/2/

Comment: @Andi Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it didn't work and it still seems like all my text attributes rotate around the same center whereas I would like them to rotate around their own lower left corner. (I removed the double transform typo in the question)

Comment: @Andi I cannot use `<div>` on my page, it has to be `<text>`. As you can see in the modified Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zhSRq/3/, your solution doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Looks like the problem is with `<text>`. Works on any other container (like div, nav, article,...)

Maybe you could use something like https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/

Didn't have worked with that before, but looks like an alternative